# Replace OracleCommand by SqlCommand [C#/ASP.NET]

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, oracle

I have to replace an OracleCommand by a SqlCommand in my code in the context of a database migration. In my code, I have the use of 
`myOracleCommand.BindByName = true;`. The property BindByName doesn't exist in the class SqlCommand so I was wondering if the SqlCommand is 'bindbyname by default' when it comes to parameters and I could thus just delete this line.

Comment: Parameters are bound by name in Sql Server. You will have to change all the parameter names in both the query and possibly the `SqlParameter` instances as well.

Comment: Yes I agree with the necessity to change the query and the instances of ``SqlParameter``. But when it comes to the line of code I mentionned in my post, you agree that I can just delete it?

Comment: Please, check names within queries: Oracle uses `:` for parameters, when MS SQL requires `@`, e.g. `select * from MyTable where id = @prm_id` -> `select * from MyTable where id = :prm_id`

Comment: @Neo - correct, you can delete that line. I also added an answer with more detail, binding by position is not possible in Sql Server which is why the SqlCommand does not have such a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore/not transfer that line (`BindByName = true`)

Parameters can only be bound by name in `SqlCommand` and never by position (which is what happens when you set `BindByName = true` in the `OracleCommand`).

---

You will have to change all the parameter names in both the query and possibly the `SqlParameter` instances as well.

In Oracle its `:paramName`, in sql server its `@paramName`. The parameter name in the `SqlParameter` instance can start with `@` or not, if not it will be added by the command when the execution occurs.

Comment: I just want to add that one can bind parameters by position with a SQL Server backend using `System.Data,Odbc` or `System.Data,OleDb`. It is only `System.Data,SqlClient` that binds by name, which is the preferred API to access SQL Server from managed code.

Comment: @DanGuzman - good point, I updated my answer to specify SqlCommand instead of Sql Server.